# SQLite/Swift 4 fastest way to convert csv values from DB to swift arrray

Tags: swift, performance, sqlite

I have a map rendering app where the map is described as an array of latitude/longitude pairs. I wish to persist these values to an SQLite database, and when it comes time to render the chart, retrieve the features, convert to an array of Doubles, and render based off that. SQLite has limited datatype support so I've inserted into SQLite a string of comma separated values. For example a line is stored as a string like this:

```
feature: "10.1,20.1,10.2,20.2"
```

When I query the db I perform the following:

```
var toBeRendered:[[Double]] = []
let coordsArray = row[coords]!.components(separatedBy: ",")

for i in 0...(coordsArray.count / 2) - 1  {
  toBeRendered.append([Double(coordsArray[i*2])!, Double(coordsArray[(i*2) + 1])!])
}
```

The problem is that for very large arrays (10-20k coordinate pairs) this method is very slow. I'm seeing 100+ ms times which is unacceptable. Does anyone have any ideas how to speed this up? I know I could cache things, and I likely will at some point, but for now the focus is making this run as fast as possible.

Thanks!

Updated: I've changed my SQLite store to the following structure. There are two tables. The first table is an r*Tree virtual index. This allows me to query to find out which features to draw. The r*Tree query is very fast, usually less than 1ms, even when the result is a few hundred objects. The output of the spatial query will be a list of feature IDs to be drawn. I take these IDs and scan the 2nd table for all matching IDs.

```
+---------+-------------+
| Field   | Type        | 
+---------+-------------+
| id      | INTEGER     |
| rTreeId | INTEGER     |
| lat     | REAL        |
| long    | REAL        |
+---------+-------------+
```

The only index I have is this (lndare is land area):

```
CREATE INDEX `lndare_coords_rtree` ON `LNDARE_COORDS` ( `rTree` ASC )
```

Lastly, the code I'm using to create the lat/long arrays:

```
for objectId in objectIds {
    //print(objectId)
    var featureContainer:[[Double]] = []
    for row in try! db.prepare(tableCoords.filter(rTreeId == objectId)) {
        featureContainer.append([row[lat], row[long]])
    }

    returnedFeatures.append(featureContainer)
}
```

Any other ideas to improve DB performance? With the code snippet above about 75% of the time is spent on db transactions, the other 25% is appending to the array.

Comment: Don't store your coordinate as a string, store them as actual doubles (sqlite REAL type) so you can just select them. Look into *one to many* database design.

Comment: @Shawn (I'm familiar w/ 1:many) are you suggesting each coordinate would have its own row? It wouldnt even be each coordinate pair, it would be each latitude and each longitude would have its own row in a separate table.

Comment: One row per lat/long tuple seems reasonable.

Comment: I implemented this approach, its roughly the same amount of time. Querying the DB for the lat/lon pairs takes a while (I have added the indexes). In my test dataset it created about 67k rows of lat/longs and I'm seeing roughly 200ms to select a few thousand of those. Thank you for the suggestion nonetheless!

Comment: You should put up your database schema (Including index definitions) and queries. There might be ways it can be improved.

Comment: Updated! Thanks for the continued help @Shawn

Answer (score 0):

Try to use split(separator: ",") otherwise reduce number of CSVs.

As most of the time is going to spend in splitting the string better reduce number of CSVs and save single lat,log as separate entity along with its relative rowID.

Comment: I tried the split method, timings stayed identical. I may try you other approach and chunk the very large elements.